# Bootstrap-vue: two different v-slot:row-details in the same table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am making a table on bootstrap-vue. Maybe someone faced such a problem. I need to display two different v-slot:row-details="row" in the same table. But only one is displayed.

```
              <template v-slot:cell(empty1)="data">
                <a
                  href="javascript:void(0)"
                  class="text-first mr-2"
                 @click="data.toggleDetails"
                >
                  <font-awesome-icon icon="key" class="mr-2" />Change Password
                </a>  
              </template>
              
              <template v-slot:row-details="data">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                  <div class="col-md-12 font-weight-bold">
                    <label>New Password</label>
                    <b-form-group>
                      <b-input-group>
                        <b-form-input class="rounded-0" type="password" v-model="password"></b-form-input>
                      </b-input-group>
                    </b-form-group>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="mt-2 d-flex align-items-center">
                      <b-button variant="warning" class="mr-2" @click="updateFTPAccount(data.item.id)">Change Password</b-button>
                      <b-button variant="outline-warning" @click="data.toggleDetails">Cancel</b-button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>  
              </template>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: I have two more similar blocks. Only there do not "Сhange password", but change other data. But only one <template v-slot: row-details = "data"> is always shown.